# matplotlib plot circular daily-cycle diagram (daily polar plot)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to plot the daily cycle of a sampling strategy as a kind of rose diagram / polar plot.

I want to show each of our experiment samples where the distance from the center is the day, and the angle from 0 represents the time at which that sample was collected. Ideally, I would like to be able to colour the points by different variables.

[image: Angle Represents the Time of Day]
[image: Distance from centre represents Day number]

The ideal plot should look something like below:

[image: Expected Output]

## Simulate dummy data to explain the problem

I have the data in an `xarray` format. We have a `launchtime` dimension that contains the time at which a sample was taken, and we want to use this to plot when in the day, and then each of the days in turn.

```py
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import pandas as pd 
from pandas.tseries.offsets import DateOffset
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import itertools

value = np.random.normal(size=100)
expected_time = pd.date_range("2000-01-01", freq="180min", periods=100)
# add random offset to simulate being +/- the true expected release time
time_deltas = np.array([DateOffset(minute=max(0, min(int(i), 59))) for i in np.abs(np.random.normal(0, 10, size=100))])
time = [expected_time[i] + time_deltas[i] if (i % 2 == 0) else expected_time[i] - time_deltas[i] for i in range(100)]

df = pd.DataFrame({"launchtime": time, "value": value})
ds = df.set_index("launchtime").to_xarray()
ds = ds.assign_coords(expected_time=("launchtime", expected_time))
```

## My thinking so far

```py
def time_to_angle(dt: pd.Timestamp) -> float:
    SEC_IN_DAY = 86_400
    start_of_day = pd.to_datetime(f"{dt.day}-{dt.month}-{dt.year}")
    delta = (dt - start_of_day)
    n_seconds = delta.seconds
    
    # return angle in degrees
    return (n_seconds / SEC_IN_DAY) * 360


# angle from 0 degrees
angles = [time_to_angle(pd.to_datetime(dt)) for dt in ds.launchtime.values]

# how far along the radius
days = np.arange(np.unique(ds["launchtime.day"].values).size)

# how to plot in polar coordinates? Do I have to draw an x,y grid and plot as a scatter?
```

Any advice on how to go about addressing this problem would be super appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

with a bit of high/secondary school trigonometry it can be quite simply achieved as a **scatter** plot.

- consider the time of day as the angle calculated in radians
- consider the day (how old) as the radius
- it then reduces to simple use of **sin()** and **cos()** to calculated **x** and **y** co-ordinates
- for good measure decided to colour points too...  not that happy with a clock face showing 24hrs,  analogue clocks only show 12 hours

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(4, 4))

df = pd.DataFrame({"sampledate":pd.date_range("01-apr-2021", "09-apr-2021 23:59", freq="30s")})
# drop a bit of data so it's not perfect circles...
df = df.loc[np.random.choice(df.index, int(len(df)/200) )]

df["angle"] = ((df["sampledate"] - df["sampledate"].dt.floor("D")).dt.total_seconds() / (24*60*60)) * 2*math.pi
df["radius"] = (df["sampledate"] - df["sampledate"].min()).dt.days+1


# scatter, radius is how old sample is, angle is time of day
ax.scatter(x=df["angle"].apply(math.sin) * df["radius"], y=df["angle"].apply(math.cos) * df["radius"], 
           c=np.where(df.sampledate.dt.hour.le(12), "red", "pink"), s=10)
ax.axis("off")

# draw markers on clock face...
for h in list(range(0, 24, 3)):
    a = (h/24)*2*math.pi
    x = math.sin(a)*df["radius"].max()
    y = math.cos(a)*df["radius"].max()
    ax.annotate(h, xy=(x, y), xytext=(x*1.1,y*1.1), backgroundcolor="yellow")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We can use the `projection="polar"` argument to the `ax = plt.subplot(projection='polar')` argument in order to create a plot with:

- the **angle** showing the time of day (`theta`, defined in radians)
- the **radius** showing number of days since the first sample (`r`).

We need to do some initial pre-processing of the time of day data and the

```py
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

def time_to_angle(dt: pd.Timestamp) -> float:
    SEC_IN_DAY = 86_400
    start_of_day = pd.to_datetime(f"{dt.day}-{dt.month}-{dt.year}")
    delta = (dt - start_of_day)
    n_seconds = delta.seconds
    
    # return angle in radians
    return (n_seconds / SEC_IN_DAY) * 2 * np.pi


# angle from 0 degrees
angles = [time_to_angle(pd.to_datetime(dt)) for dt in ds.launchtime.values]

# how far along the radius = DAY NUM 
le = LabelEncoder()
days = le.fit_transform(ds["launchtime.dayofyear"].values)


# Use the polar projection plot from matplotlib
ax = plt.subplot(projection='polar')
ax.set_theta_direction(-1)
ax.set_theta_zero_location("N")
ax.scatter(angles, days, marker="o")
ax.set_xticklabels(['00:00', '03:00', '06:00', '09:00', '12:00', '15:00', '18:00', '21:00',])
ax.set_yticklabels([])
ax.set_title("Sampling Schedule [UTC]")
plt.show()
```

The output looks something like this:

[image: Matplotlib Polar Projection Plot]